# Debugging: How do I observe a publisher's data?

Tags: ios, debugging, combine

How do I peer into the data portion of this publisher? 
I want to decipher the data (via **String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8)**) during debug.

```
func getList<Resource>(urlDataModel: Resource) where Resource: URLResource {
        let remoteDataPublisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: urlDataModel.url!)
            .map(\.data)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .decode(type: Resource.DataModel.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .print("getList: ")
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code; post the code itself into the [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I made the change per request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `handleEvents` operator:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
   .map(\.data)
   .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { data in
      print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
   })
   .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
   .decode(type: Resource.DataModel.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
```